# How does the viscosity (besides density) of a fluid affects sinking?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag, density, viscosity

If water, air of whatever fluid had a different viscosity, but the same density, would things fall/sink differently?

Comment: [Related Quora Would-a-hydrophobic-coating-make-a-heavy-object-sink-through-water-faster] (http://quora.com/Science/Would-a-hydrophobic-coating-make-a-heavy-object-sink-through-water-faster)

Answer (score 2):

Yes they would fall differently.

For example, according to [Stokes' Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) the drag force is proportional to [dynamic viscosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_viscosity#Dynamic_viscosity) and the terminal velocity of a falling sphere is:

$$\frac{2(\rho_s -\rho_f)}{9\mu}gR^2$$

where $\rho_s$ and $\rho_f$ are the densities of the sphere, $\mu$ is the dynamic viscosity, $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, and $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

Answer (score 2):

The *dynamics* in case of relative motion will be different: e.g., the acceleration and terminal velocity when falling/sinking. But the equilibrium will be unaffected (e.g., floating and waterline). This is because viscosity is at the origin of a frictional force.